# Alternative to multi-binding and converters?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android

I'm looking for an alternative for two reasons:

1. Multi-binding and converters are not available for Xamarin.Android (correct me if I'm wrong).
2. Binding requires atleast one side to be a dependency property (which sucks).

I'll try to explain what I want through code:

Given classes Foo and Bar:

```
class Foo
{
    int a;
    int A
    {
        get { return a; }

        set
        {
            if (a == value)
                return;

            a = value;

            AChanged();
        }
    }


    int b;
    int B
    {
        get { return b; }


        set
        {
            if (b == value)
                return;

            b = value;

            BChanged();
        }
    }

    event Action AChanged;

    event Action BChanged;

}

class Bar
{
    int C { get; set; }
}
```

and method Add:

```
    int Add(int a, int b)
    {

        return a + b;
    }
```

and instances foo and bar, I would like for `bar.C` to be bound to `foo.A` and `foo.B` through the `Add` function. In other words, when either A or B change, I want the following to statement to be executed:

```
bar.C = Add(foo.A, foo.B);
```

So I'm wondering if some solution exists that can eliminate boilerplate code. For example:

```
var binding = Binder.Bind(Add, ()=> bar.C, () => foo.A, () => foo.B);

binding.Enabled = true;
```

Obviously this can be done manually but when you have 10s of properties from different classes with each one having one or more dependencies, the code gets messy.

Events can be detected through a naming convention (e.g., ProperyNameChanged)

I'm merely asking whether such a solution exists so I don't reinvent the wheel.

P.S., English is clearly not my first language. Feel free to correct any grammar mistakes. If you can also rephrase the question in a more concise way it would great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to look at https://github.com/Muraad/Bind which is based on https://github.com/praeclarum/Bind. Its only one file. If just changed it, now its working with a method call on the right side of a binding. I´v included your example as a test case.

One can write

```
var foo = new Foo() { A = 0, B = 0 };
var bar = new Bar();

// Bind bar.C to the right side of the == expression
IDisposable binding = NBind.Create(() => bar.C == Adder.Add(foo.A, foo.B));
foo.A = 42;
// bar.C is 42 now
foo.B = 42;
// bar.C is 84 now
```

The only requirement is that Foo implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I'm looking for, it even uses the same example :) By the way, it also supports other naming conventions (e.g., PropertyNameChanged)

Just curious, did you lookup it now or have already known about it?

Comment: Its nice to hear. Iread your question then i thought about the Bind library i was forking. Then i tried to implement your example and saw that it was not working with a function call on the right side and fixed it. So yes it is your example :)

Comment: If I may ask, why did you remove support for other event names/types?

Comment: I thought it was a very unique requirement of the original https://github.com/praeclarum/Bind founder. And it was not generic. I thought removing it is reducing the complexity of the code. Maybe i will add it again, but in a more generic way. For example one should be able to register many different event names/types.